# Are these things MathType's fault?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

In the [comments after a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136511/interchanging-two-limits-in-a-proof-is-it-legitimate#comment314456_136511), Peter Tamaroff mentioned using MathType.  I am not familiar with that software.  Apparently it is being blamed for such solecisms as

{ \int_{0}^{1} } { { x^{2} } }\,{ { {d}{x} } },

etc., where

\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx

would serve.  I think the presence of so much of that sort of thing in math.stackexchange.com is a disservice to those who edit postings and learn how to code things in $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$ by doing so.

Is MathType the principal source of this, or are there others?

Is the [terrible practice of using \mbox{}](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Mathematics/Why_you_should_never_use_%5Cmbox_within_Wikipedia) instead of \text{} also the fault of MathType?  In the normal use of $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$, as opposed to its use in web forums, \mbox{} does not cause things to appear in text mode that would otherwise be in math mode, and serves a completely different purpose that seems inapplicable to forums on the web.

Comment: I have answered your concern, I hope.

Comment: Well, you haven't answered the question about \mbox.

Comment: Hmph... as I recall from my days with $\TeX$, using `\mbox{}` *does* cause things to appear in text mode; anything inside the `\mbox` is processed in paragraph mode, even if inside math mode (I use to use it to do cases when typing in plain-$\TeX$, before I switched over to $\LaTeX$).

Comment: I guess this is related to the earlier questions http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/tex-usage-in-stackexchange and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/tex-style-manual

Answer (score 2):

I think that MathType produces these types of enconding for the sole reason it has templates for each type of symbol.

Say I need to use $$\sum\limits_{\square}^{\square}\square$$

Then the template will look as a fill in the blanks thing, like this:

`$$\sum\limits_{}^{} {} $$`

When one fills it in the interface, the program fills the `{}` accordingly, and you get what you want. 
$$ $$
Simiarily, say if i want to use $$\int_{\square}^{\square}\square$$ the template will be

`$$\int\limits_{}^{} {} $$`

The third pair of `{}` is where the integrand goes. So what you see is a union of all these to be filled $\{$ and $\}$

I personally know some $\TeX$, but coding lots of equations makes me waste time, so when I need to code something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117246/evaluation-of-the-integral-int-01-frac-ln1-x1-xdx/117340#117340) I use it.

Comment: How do things like y = { \left( { x + 2 } \right)\left( {x+3} \right)} instead of y=(x+2)(x+3) get there?

Comment: Is MathType also responsible for the misuse of \mbox?

Comment: MathType has a $\left( \square \right)$ template for delimiters. It is the same as what I just explained. I don't think `\mbox` stems from MT.

Comment: The template code would be `$$\left( {} \right)$$`

Comment: That last one seems like a clear case where the braces serve no purpose.  With something like \int_{}^{}, the braces serve a purpose when the subscript or superscript has more than one character.  But in \int_{}^{}{}, the last set of braces seems to serve no purpose, and likewise in the last example you mention.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well, then you have to talk to the MT developers. They'll sure have a reason why to include them.

Comment: Does MathType involve pointing and clicking?  If so, I would think it would be slow and cumbersome compared to just typing the $\TeX$ code.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My problem with coding is my keyboard, as opposed to the English one, has not a direct key to { , } , \ or ^, but I rather need AltGr and Shift for each one. It makes it a pain in the ....arm to type them.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I can't speak to the MathType-$\mathrm\LaTeX$ conversion, but it is quite possible to use MathType entirely from the keyboard and be mighty fast with it.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I recommend switching to some kind of English keyboard when you need to use a lot of those symbols. It doesn't take long to get used to.  My laptop keyboard has the German layout printed on it, but I use the US one most of the time.

Comment: @Isaac Indeed, MT has lots of shortcuts to use. For example, Ctrl+I inserts an integral template, Ctrl+9 the delimiters, Ctrl+S the sum, Ctrl+H the superindex and Ctrl+L the subindex, etc. This makes coding quite fast if you have to ask.